# WebAPI receive byte array content as method varialbe

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to send data compressed to my server to save traffic volume.

I was able to do so by sending the data in `Json` format

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBytes([FromBody] byte[] bytes)
{
}
```

But i want to send the data as `application/octet-stream`.

I have tried using this code:

```
retVal = await PostAsync(url, compressedData, headers);

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(
    string url,
    byte[] baContent,
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers = null,
    int timeoutMili = 30000)
{
    HttpResponseMessage retVal = null;

    HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();


    //ssl
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    //create the request
    using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
    {
        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(baContent))
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            request.Content = content;
            request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }

            //send the request
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMili);
            retVal = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

But I am getting this error: `Unable to translate bytes [9C] at index 1 from specified code page to Unicode.`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from my searching, WebAPI doesn't know how to format raw byte[] body content to a variable. So I switched to this code which works:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBytes()
{
    byte[] content = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
```

Comment: I spent 4 hours trying to solve this, and when I finally got it working, I found your answer. Your answer is correct: When there is a parameter, WebAPI tries to parse the data and bind that to the parameter. The problem is that out of the box it parses only JSON or XML. So the only way to make it work with `application/octet-stream` is not specifying any parameter at all on the method, and parsing the request body manually, as you did...